# printing from multidimensional arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multi array that looks like this:

```
$_SESSION['cartItems']['quantity']
```

How do I print out its values? `print_r` won't work, unless `$_SESSION` doesn't support multi-dimensional arrays?

Answer (score 0):

`print_r($_SESSION['cartItems']);` should work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use var_dump($_SESSION). However, print_r should work. Make sure you are doing print_r($_SESSION), and not trying to print_r your variable that may not exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the quantity of each card item in the array, you can do this:

```
$quantities = array_map(create_function('item', "$item['quanitity']"), $_SESSION['cardItems']);

// PHP 5.3
$quantities = array_map(function($item) {
    return $item['quanitity'];
}, $_SESSION['cardItems']);
```